# In VHDL, is there a limit to how many ANDs and ORs one can have in an if statement?

Tags: vhdl

If I have slv_flag(11 downto 0) and others, is there a limit to the number of ANDs and ORs?

```
If slv_flag(1) = '1' and slv_this(3) = '0' and slv_that(7) = '1' and int_count > 353 then
     slv_action <= "10101010";
end if;


If (slv_flag(1) = '1' and slv_flag(3) = '0' and slv_flag(7) = '1' and slv_flag(12) = '0') or slv_flag(0) = '1' then
         slv_action <= "10101011";
    end if;
```

Comment: The language itself has no limit to expression complexity. A condition is an expression providing a Boolean value. There can be an implementation limits based on the expression stack size. Operators (iEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2)  can be implemented using subprograms (4.5.2 Operator overloading)  that when called are dynamically elaborated (14.6). Operand size and expression complexity can affect the requirement for expression stack space. Stack space would be retired on sequential statement boundaries (which includes parameter expressions of procedure calls).